# ASP file.How do i make it work?

Tags: html

I have written a ASP file and saved in my D: drive as demo.asp to get the data from my HTML file.

```
              <form action="d:\test\demo.asp" method="get">
              Your name: <input type="text" name="fname" size="20" />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                     </form>
```

But it is not working.

```
             <%
                 dim fname
                 fname=Request.QueryString("fname")
                 If fname<>"" Then
                 Response.Write("Hello " & fname & "!<br />")
                 Response.Write("How are you today?")
                 End If
             %>
```

And also some ASP codes have < html >< /html > tags in them.Why we mention them in our ASP file.I read on google that ASP is a server scripting language.Thats true I think so.because Im unable to run demo.asp. But I dont have any webserver to load the ASP files to make it run But i want to see how my code is working on.How can i check The written ASP file performing the required task?And can i also use perl or python script in my ASP? Is there any neccesary things I have to make before  i  use perl as a scripting language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I dont have any webserver to load the ASP files to make it run

Since ASP is only processed by webservers — get one.

> And can i also use perl or python script in my ASP?

[You can sort-of use Perl](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/Components/Windows/PerlScript.html#active_server_pages), via ActiveState's PerlScript.

I'd strongly advice not using ASP if you want to use those languages though. I can't speak for Python, but in Perl-land [Plack](http://plackperl.org/) is currently the favoured way to run web based Perl stuff. You might want to look at using it in combination with [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/).

You can use [Mason](http://www.masonhq.com/) if you want to embed Perl in your HTML documents. I'd suggest separating out your concerns and keeping the HTML templates separate from the Perl code using [Template-Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/).

Comment: That runs ASP? I think Windows comes with one. I've managed to avoid ASP + VBScript, it is too proprietary. For the other options (including ASP with PerlScript), [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org) is fine.